# How to edit text on a Django class based form

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to edit the text rendered to the form in the template. But I cannot find a way to do it in class based views and only in function based views.

[image]

In the image above, I want to change the text 'image' to 'thumbnail'.

Views (Both edit and create view):

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PostEdit, CreateView):
    fields = ['title', 'youtube_url', 'text', 'image', 'job_type']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PostEdit, UpdateView):
    fields = ['title', 'youtube_url', 'text', 'image', 'job_type']
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of changing the field's title of a `ModelForm`. One of these is to use the [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) property of the field. In your case you probably have a model like so:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    # Some other fields
```

What you need to do is to change this to the following:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(..., verbose_name='Thumbnail')
```

Then Django will use the provided `verbose_name` when instantiating a `ModelForm` for `MyModel`